# How to move the home directory of current user into another place, in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp

Current, the home of current user is:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\freewind
```

It contains many other directories, e.g. `My Documents`, `Desktop`

Now I want to move the whole directory to another place, for example:

```
D:\freewind
```

Then if I want to run this Java code:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.home"))
```

It will print `D:\freewind`.

Is it possible?

Comment: Here's a [fairly long description](http://www.starkeith.net/coredump/2009/05/18/how-to-move-your-windows-user-profile-to-another-drive/), might be helpful. But it depends on what you really need. Java only reads the `%USERPROFILE%` environmental variable.

Comment: @slhck, it's long, but it's I expected :) Please copy your comment as an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java uses the `%USERPROFILE%` environmental variable, but if you want to move the home directory to some other folder or other drive, this is a bit tricky.

Here is a very well explained blog post about [how to move the Windows User Profile to another directory](http://www.starkeith.net/coredump/2009/05/18/how-to-move-your-windows-user-profile-to-another-drive/), written by Keith Survell.

The idea is to use [NTFS junction points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point). Here are the basic steps:

- Make a thorough backup
- Create a second user account and log into this one
- Move the complete user's directory contents to the new folder, e.g. from `C:\Users\JohnDoe` to `C:\JohnDoe`. This can be done by just drag/dropping in Windows Explorer.
- Rename the old User directory to something else (e.g. `JohnDoe.old`)
- Open the command prompt and enter

  ```
  mklink /J C:\Users\JohnDoe C:\JohnDoe
  ```
- Log out of the temporary user profile

<sub>Keith appears to like Super User. I couldn't find you though. If you're reading this, please feel free to expand or comment!</sub>

Comment: I'm not hard to find ;-) I'm glad people still find that article helpful!

Answer (score 0):

If you run lusrmgr.msc, you can change the user profile location. Select a user in Users, right click and click "Properties". Then go to "Profile" tab. By default, the "Home folder" has an empty Local path (which is really C:\Documents and Settings\username). Just put the new path in it.

Comment: I have tried of this, but it doesn't work. After rebooting, all my programs will still treat "C:\Documents and Settings\freewind" as the user home.