# rename home directory of a user

Tags: windows, windows-8

My Windows 8.1 laptop decided it didn't want to boot.  So I refreshed the OS -- basically a new install of Windows.  That worked.  It promised to keep my files, which it did.  But it moved them from

```
C:\Users\William
```

to

```
C:\Users\UpdatusUser
```

That's strange.  It also broke a bunch of my aliases.  Can I change my home directory back?  I obviously don't want to mess things up again.

I did see the idea to use junctions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/332626/how-to-move-the-home-directory-of-current-user-into-another-place-in-windows-xp).  But that's pretty old.  Additionally, is that really necessary?  Obviously, the system was able to move the folder when I did the update.  If it can be moved once, surely it can be moved again, in a way that is totally clean and transparent.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the profile migration wizzard tool from http://www.forensit.com/downloads.html it should work.